# datatables gives [object Object] as column value

Tags: javascript, datatables

In my datatable it shows `[object Object],[object Object]` value for one column.
I pass data as below.

```
columns: [

                {"data": "id"},
                {"data": "ruleName"},
                {"data": "ruletype"},
                {"data": "valid-from"},
                {"data": "valid-to"},
                {"data": "status"},
                {"data": "tiers"},
                {"data": "Attributes"},
                {"data": "Actions"}
            ],
```

in here    `{"data": "Attributes"},` gives [object Object],[object Object] .
how can I convert it to string values?

Comment: Recheck your mRender && mDataProp attributes.

Comment: _“how can I convert it to string values?”_ - that _is_ already what has happened, that’s _why_ you got `[object Object]`. You either need to add a `toString` method to those objects, that takes care of the job of converting them into a string value in the way you like, or you need to access the actual, scalar values contained inside `Attributes` individually. (The latter probably makes less sense, if the number of attributes is variable.)

Comment: btw how your response looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should look like this:

```
var columns = {
                data: "id",
                data1: "ruleName",
                data2: "ruletype",
                data3: "valid-from",
                data4: "valid-to",
                data5: "status",
                data6: "tiers",
                data7: "Attributes",
                data8: "Actions"
            }

//This should give you all the values

console.log(columns);
```

Comment: other values are gives correctly. only " Attributes" gives that result

Comment: will you please show how you are displaying the values in view ? @maneesha5

Comment: Try this approach, how are you gonna be sorting the data when all the names are **data**, just seems as bad approach

Comment: [{"name":"Registration","value":"registration","uuid":"e4c7693c-2c39-b833-9293-c48501dd7918"},{"name":"Ref_Registration","value":"ref_registration","uuid":"0cc81b29-bc20-ab45-e0eb-fc08345d8e9a"}]

Comment: try changing it any luck?

Comment: So what is the output now after you changed it to my code?

Comment: `[{"name":"Registration","value":"registration","uuid":"e4c7693c-2c39-b833-9293-c48501dd7918"},{"name":"Ref_Registration","value":"ref_registration","uuid":"0cc81b29-bc20-ab45-e0eb-fc08345d8e9a"}]`  Is this the data in `Attributes`?  Which of these values do you want to display?  Maybe you want to display `name` you would use `{"data": "Attributes.name"},` in the code of your original post.

Comment: can you post a bit more of the code because the problem doesnt seem to be here.